# Showing a string instea of a dropwdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm working With React Multiple Select to enable a dropdown list that allows multiple selections, I want it to show data from the server a but it brings it as one single string. Tried the next two ways:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);


const options = hours?.map ((list, index) => {return list}) 
const listOfHours = [{label: options, value: options}]

          <MultiSelect
        options={listOfHours}
        value={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        labelledBy="Select"
        />
```

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
 
const listOfHours = [{label: settings?.time, value: settings?.time}]

      <MultiSelect
     options={listOfHours}
     value={selected}
     onChange={setSelected}
     labelledBy="Select"
     />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options` should be an array of objects:

```
const listOfHours = hours.map(hour => ({label:hour.time, value:hour.time}))
```

what you were doing there is giving `options` an array of one object